# Is there ESLint or TSLint rule that checks that truthy/falsy logical operator is not applied to numbers?

Tags: javascript, typescript, numbers, eslint, lint

I had a bug today where I unexpectedly skip a call to a function because my variable was 0:

```
const foo: number | undefined = getFoo();
if(foo) {
   // Will not be called if foo is zero
   doSomething(foo);
}
```

This is a pattern I use pretty often, testing if a variable is defined. This works with everything, objects, arrays, strings... Except number.
This is not the 1st time I got a bug like this.

Is there a rule that will alert me, something like:

```
if(foo)
   --- Warning, testing a number variable that can be defined, but equals to zero
```

Something that will force me to write:

```
if(foo !== undefined)
```

It is less pretty, but at least it has the correct behaviour.

Edit: after thinking about this, it appears that the same problem can occur with the type `string` and the value `""` (empty string)

Comment: Is the situation you care about only inside an `if`, like in the code above?

Comment: I am unsure I understand your question fully, but yes, generally it is only inside the `if` that I want the linter to alert me.

Comment: It doesn't looks too complicated, but TSLint is going down soon, and I have never work on ESLint, I don't know how the code compares to TSLint (where at least I know the code a little)

Comment: I don't think eslint would provide type information (if tslint have), so it would be quite complicated.

Comment: You will likely have to create your own rule. Refer https://eslint.org/docs/developer-guide/working-with-plugins for writing your own ESLint rules.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`tslint` has [strict-boolean-expressions](https://palantir.github.io/tslint/rules/strict-boolean-expressions/).

Answer (score 3):

For Typescript ESLint (as TSLint has been deprecated), there is a rule with the same name that [Zbigniew Zagórski](https://stackoverflow.com/users/269448) mentioned in the other answer: [strict-boolean-expressions](https://github.com/typescript-eslint/typescript-eslint/blob/master/packages/eslint-plugin/docs/rules/strict-boolean-expressions.md)

Comment: https://typescript-eslint.io/rules/strict-boolean-expressions/